# Base of vectors in $\mathbb{Z}_5$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vectors

I have little problem.
$$((2,4),(1,0))$$ How can I check its base in $\mathbb{ Z}_5^2$ ? Can I just do classic methods like in other set of numbers? Or is it different?

Comment: A basis for what?  The subspace that it generates?  Something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to write it in matrix form: $\begin{pmatrix} 2 & 1\\4 & 0\end{pmatrix}$, viewed as matrix over $\mathbb{Z}_5$.

Then argue that this matrix lies in $\operatorname{GL}_2(\mathbb{Z}_5)$ by showing that its determinant is invertible in $\mathbb{Z}_5$.